# Ant + Ivy: Resolving spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ant, ivy

In my spring webapplication I am trying to get my dependencies resolved by Ivy. So here's my setup:

`ivy.xml`: http://pastebin.com/sDykaRn4 
`ivysettings.xml`: http://pastebin.com/NmQsdG2m 
`build.xml`: http://pastebin.com/Z5Z2XmmW 
`web.xml`: http://pastebin.com/r06wbLr5 
`/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml`: http://pastebin.com/F4bdPyr4

My dependencies are getting well resolved by Ivy into my `.ivy2/cache` folder and then copied to `lib.dir`. The report gives me the following conflicts:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      compile     |  257  |  223  |  221  |   50  ||  204  |  204  |
|      runtime     |  248  |  215  |  213  |   48  ||  197  |  197  |
|       test       |  249  |  216  |  214  |   48  ||  198  |  198  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Module  Selected    Evicted
xercesImpl by xerces    2.10.0  2.8.1 2.8.0
xml-apis by xml-apis    1.4.01  1.3.02 1.3.04 1.3.03
jaxen by jaxen  1.1.4   1.1.1
jsch by com.jcraft  0.1.51  0.1.42
commons-io by commons-io    1.4 1.3.2 1.3
xalan by xalan  2.7.1   2.7.0
slf4j-api by org.slf4j  1.7.12  1.5.3 1.5.8 1.6.1
backport-util-concurrent by backport-util-concurrent    3.1 3.0
poi by org.apache.poi   3.12    3.0.2-FINAL
commons-codec by commons-codec  1.9 1.6 1.2
commons-lang by commons-lang    2.6 2.3 2.4 2.1
tiles-jsp by org.apache.tiles   2.1.2   3.0.1
tiles-servlet by org.apache.tiles   2.1.2   3.0.1
tiles-core by org.apache.tiles  2.1.2   3.0.1
tiles-api by org.apache.tiles   3.0.1   2.1.2
spring-web by org.springframework   3.2.4.RELEASE   2.5.6
jackson-mapper-asl by org.codehaus.jackson  1.4.2   1.5.2
httpcore by org.apache.httpcomponents   4.2 4.0-beta1
servlet-api by javax.servlet    2.5 2.4 2.3
activation by javax.activation  1.1 1.0.2
jcommon by jfree    1.0.16  1.0.0
commons-logging by commons-logging  1.2 1.1.1 1.0 1.1 1.1.3 1.0.4 1.0.3
commons-digester by commons-digester    2.1 1.8 1.8.1 2.0
commons-collections by commons-collections  20040616    2.0 3.2.1 3.2 3.1
commons-beanutils by commons-beanutils  1.7.0   1.8.3
itext by com.lowagie    2.1.7   [1.02b,)
joda-time by joda-time  2.1 1.6.2
log4j by log4j  1.2.17  1.2.16 1.2.14
```

When I try to start my tomcat server in Eclipse, the server won't start (well, it does start, but with lots of Errors) and prints this log: http://pastebin.com/dtA6vFcK

My research on the `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` suggested that I am using multiple versions of spring. But as you can see in my ivy file and report, I only use 3.2.4.RELEASE. And I don't see how any of those ivy conflicts would harm the startup of my spring application.
Here's a list of the jars in my `lib.dir`: http://pastebin.com/01E2CQrx

Do you might see any problem...?

Thank you so much... really need your help on this one.

Comment: You have a "Could not load JDBC driver class org.sqlite.JDBC". This has nothing to do with spring in my opinion. Try adding the required jar and class to your classpath

Comment: Agreed. You are missing a sqlite dependency.

Comment: You guys are the best! I only focussed on the BeanCreationException while completely ignoring the JDBC error. Including `<dependency org="org.xerial" name="sqlite-jdbc" rev="3.8.10.1" conf="runtime->default"/>` fixed my issue! Thank you very very much!